# Modulus calculation for compound primary keys in MySQL Cluster (and other sharded databases)

Tags: mysql, partitioning, scalability, sharding

In MySQL Cluster, and generally in sharded databases, how is a compound primary key's modulus calculated?

Say, for example, there are two tables that have primary keys like so:

```
CREATE TABLE Orders (order_id INT PRIMARY KEY, ...);
CREATE TABLE LineItems (order_id INT, lineitem_id INT, PRIMARY KEY (order_id, lineitem_id), ...);
```

I saw this example in [a Quora question about sharding MySQL tables](http://qr.ae/2PbUl), where it is specifically mentioned as a good idea for sharding if `Orders` and `LineItems` are to be queried together.

How is the modulus calculated so that rows with the same `order_id` are on the same shard?