# Would an INNER JOIN query in a sharded relational database hit the same shard when using a compound primary key?

Tags: mysql, relational-theory, scalability, sharding

In [this question I have asked about modulus calculation in sharded tables](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/68752/21243), this design is used:

```
CREATE TABLE Orders (order_id INT PRIMARY KEY, ...);
CREATE TABLE LineItems (order_id INT, lineitem_id INT, PRIMARY KEY (order_id, lineitem_id), ...);
```

I would like to perform an `INNER JOIN` query so that the whole result set is gathered from a single shard in MySQL Cluster (or, for that matter, a sharded database), like so:

```
SELECT * from Orders INNER JOIN LineItems on Orders.order_id = LineItems.order_id where order_id <some_id>;
```

The idea would be that this query hit only a specific shard.  Is that how a sharded database works?  What needs to happen in order for that to be true?

Comment: I suggest you add the `[mysql]` tag.

Comment: Cheers! Added :)